# Sending multiple report subscriptions in Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have about 15-18 reports I need to email out via Report Manager subscriptions. They are mid-size reports, not enormous. Each runs in a couple seconds.

I went to the trouble to space out the subscriptions, a couple minutes apart, but this is tedious. Is it necessary?

Can I just set up all 15 reports to send at 12:15am? Will they get appropriately queued up and sent as they complete, or am I risking grinding things to a halt?

I'm fairly new to SSRS, and I see that my predecessor spread things out. Just not sure it's necessary.

I'm using SQL 2012 standard. Enterprise isn't an option for me.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem.. if the reports are fairly quick.. go for it. 15 - 20 reports is almost nothing.. some do it in the 100s or even 1000s. The limiting fact is the server spec of course..

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is if running the reports at the same time can interfere with each other. From what I can tell, they are not queued up in sequence, it tries to run them all in parallel.

For example, I've had issues where if I run two reports at the same time on SQL Server, they cause a deadlock. Of course there are ways around this, but it is something to consider.

Also, the more reports you run at the same time, the more resources it requires. So at some point, certain reports will start timing out. You'll have to do some load testing to see how much your servers can handle based on your resources and requirements.